# TYPE Rotation Vector Sensor

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors

In the sensor list Rotation Vector Sensor is shown as a sensor in my phone Huawei Ascend.But when I use it in a App Rotation Vector sensor is not showing any output.I cant figure out what is the actual reason for that, Im sure that the code has no errors.Plz help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rotation vector sensor needs derives the values from accelerometer and gyroscope [Source](http://%20https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types)where Gyroscope is consider as primary sensor. Huawei Ascend doesn't have gyroscope sensor in build. It might able to genrate the values because of that.